# How to access element name using attribute value from Xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have an XML file with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<car_ads>
<car_make make="suzuki" adj_kw="null">
<model data_type="string"adj_kw="null" class="کار_ماڈل ">
   <model_instance>ALTO</model_instance>
   <model_instance>KHYBER</model_instance>
</model>
<year data_type="integer" adj_kw="yes" class="ایر ">
   <adj_kw>ماڈل </adj_kw>
   <adj_kw>ء</adj_kw>
</year>
<price data_type="string" adj_kw="yes" class=" قیمت  " >
    <adj_kw>قیمت  </adj_kw>
    <adj_kw>ڈیمانڈ </adj_kw>
</price>
</car_make>
<car_make make="سوزوکی" adj_kw="null">
<model data_type="string" adj_kw="null" class="کار_ماڈل ">
    <model_instance>alto</model_instance>
    <model_instance>آلٹو</model_instance>
</model>
<year data_type="integer" adj_kw="yes" class="ایر ">
    <adj_kw>ماڈل </adj_kw>
    <adj_kw>ء</adj_kw>
    <adj_kw>ایئرآفمینوفیکچرنگ </adj_kw>
</year>
<price data_type="string" adj_kw="yes" class=" قیمت  " >
    <adj_kw>قیمت  </adj_kw>
    <adj_kw>ڈیمانڈ </adj_kw>
</price>
</car_make>
</car_ads>
```

I am parsing this using XmlDocument in c#

```
string xmlText = File.ReadAllText(@"G:\\car_xml_final.xml");
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
```

If I know attribute value (e.g.in my example attribute class =" ایر") I want to get its corresponding element name (i.e element= "year").

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Charles Mager for pointing out the difference between `XmlDocument` and `XDocument`. If you use `XDocument`, you can use either LINQ:

```
var element = doc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("class") == " ایر");
var elementName = element.Name;
```

or XPath:

```
var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("//[@class=' ایر']");
var elementName = element.Name;
```

to get your desired result.

If you stick to `XmlDocument`, there's the [`SelectSingleNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var element = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("descendant::[class=""' ایر'""]");
```

Comment: its giving me error: system.Xml.XmlDocument does not  contain definition for XPathSelectElement. i have included  system.Xml.XPath;

Comment: What error? Did you include the necessary `using` directives?

Comment: You're using `XmlDocument`. This answer uses LINQ to XML (`XDocument`). Parse using that (it's a far better API).

Comment: i have done all my coding using XmlDocument. what if i want to do it using XmlDocument.

Comment: error again: XPathException was unhandled . Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use `SelectSingleNode()` or `SelectNodes()` to get sepcific element(s) from `XmlDocument` passing an XPath expression as parameter, for example :

```
var result = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@class='ایر ']");
foreach (XmlNode node in result)
{
    //print element name
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
}
```

**brief explanation about XPath being used :**

- `//*` : select all elements regardless of the name (`*`), anywhere in the XML document (`//`)...
- `[@class='some_class_here']` : ...having class attribute value equals certain class name